# Can my asp.net application make a call to a linux server, speficially some shell script?

Tags: asp.net

If I have a asp.net web app on a windows box (obviously!), and I need to execute a shell script that is on a linux server, is that possible?

How can I do this safely?

Comment: Does the ASP.NET webapp need to receive/process a response from the shell script?

Comment: yes, now that i think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build on what cxfx has said above your best bet might be to set up a web server on the linux box, and build a web service using, for example, php.

php allows you to run shell scripts - so by calling a web page runscript.php and then using exec (http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) you could run the script.

Security is a consideration - you could restrict access to the linux web server purely to the IP address of the server hosting your asp.net site?

Hope that helps.

Comment: Good plan.  Security is definitely the biggest issue here, so be careful not to do anything crazy like pass the name of the script in the querystring!

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is by logging through ssh. You can use the [granados](http://www.routrek.co.jp/en/product/varaterm/granados.html) C# library for it. This will let you run arbitrary commands. If what you need is to always run the same command, you can take a different approach like a CGI script (hide it with at least HTTPS and user/password).

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet might be to expose the triggering of the shell script through some sort of web interface, like a secure web service.